# Typing References in typescript are case sensitive?

Tags: windows, import, typescript, visual-studio-2015, naming-conventions

I use visual studio 2015 in a project with typescript and the files are named using lower and capital letters like this "project/Models/myFile.ts". 
When I want to import something from another module/file I use drag n drop in Visual studio so as to provide me automatically the reference with the path of the file, but it ignores capital letters and gives a path all in lowercase.

**Question 1:** Does this means that Visual studio is not case sensitive when referencing or importing files in typescript?

**Question 2:** Is it recommended to use all lowercase letters for naming folders and files, in order to be compatible with different Operating Systems?

**UPDATE**
The path given in the reference comments `/// <reference path="jquery" />` seems to be case insensitive so this `/// <reference path="JQuery" />`  works the same, but when using the import keyword, the path must much the exact naming of the file containing the module.

Comment: See TypeScript issue [3626](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3626). They introduced a new commandline argument: --forceConsistentCasingInFileNames

Comment: Thanks I need to check that

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1: Does this means that Visual studio is not case sensitive when referencing or importing files in typescript?

It's case insensitive on Windows; however, I have found it's case sensitive at run-time only on some other operating systems like Linux. I ran into this problem one time when changing the casing standards in an application and everything worked fine until the code was [run on the Linux CI](https://travis-ci.org/dsherret/ts-type-info/builds/115202799).

In order to make code portable, it's important to make sure the casing in a module specifier matches the referenced file name exactly.

> Question 2: Is it recommended to use all lowercase letters for naming folders and files, in order to be compatible with different Operating Systems?

This is a personal preference. For example, I prefer to make my file names have the same casing as the name of what is exported and this is what is recommend in [some style guides](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--filename-matches-export). Some other people prefer to use kebab casing (ex. `some-file-name.ts`) while others prefer to use some other casing style.

Comment: Windows OSs are not case sensitive but on the other hand, Unix do, so I guess it is a good idea to have all lowercase names to avoid big troubles.

Comment: @Konst if the code is only being testing in a Windows environment then yes that would definitely reduce the chance of error, but if it's also tested on a case sensitive OS then it becomes a non-issue and you can use the casing standard you prefer.

Comment: I never liked the relation between file names (some random packaging in my eyes) with a module name. Restrictions like multiple modules per file not being allowed ensue which turn it even more ugly. It might save a few lines in the compiler/transpiler code but for end users ... I never liked it...

Comment: Hi @DavidSherret, what do you mean exactly with "to make code portable" ? thx

Comment: @Funder on Linux the module specifiers will be case sensitive. For example, if the file name is `MyFile.ts`, but the module specifier is `"./myfile.ts"` this will work on Windows, but not Linux. Making the code portable here just means you'll want to use `"./MyFile"` as the module specifier in order for it to work on both platforms.

Comment: But module specifier is not a filename, how is that managed by typescript? I just created a new question, can you check it please? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943333/typescript-configuration-is-module-setting-case-sensitive 
thank you!

Comment: @Funder module specifiers is the part in the string in import declarations (ex. the string in `import * as a from "./MyFile.ts"`). It's not related to the "module" compiler option.

Comment: Ohhh... @DavidSherret I totally see what you mean now, I was fried the other day! :-D